# Why does socket.accept() break the unfinished established connection?

Tags: python, sockets

I have searched a lot of posts but could not find an answer. I understand that the `socket.accept()` actually fetches the socket from fully-connected queue. Also, I know because of the blocking IO, we have to rely on the concurrent for multiple connections.

However, my question is what else does `socket.accept()` do? **Will it break established connections**? In my experiment, I use one thread to accept a new connection and **leaves it alone**. In other words, I do NOT `recv()` intentionally because I want to hold every requests in the effort to keep **multiple** connections.

I use several clients to send messages. Surprisingly, only one connection can sustain. The following is my code.

On the server side (on a Linux server):

```
import time
import socket

HOST = "0.0.0.0"  
PORT = 65432 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
```

On the client side (on the Macbook):

```
import socket

HOST = "192.168.0.104"
PORT = 65432


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while True:
    print('connect')
    s.send(b"Hello, world")
```

When I start the server, the first client got blocked. When I start the second client, the first client existed with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home/xxx/test-client.py", line 14, in <module>
    s.send(b"Hello, world")
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

while the second client got blocked.

My question is:

1. I expect the server can hold multiple connections, but why only one can sustain?
2. If `socket.accept()` always breaks the established connections, why concurrent can work well?

---

As @Mark Tolonen answered, the cause is the garbage-collection. When I use the following snippet, I can see multiple connections sustained.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import socket

HOST = "0.0.0.0"  
PORT = 65432 

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()

connections = []
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    connections.append(conn)
```

---

I would like to thank you all for your help, but would like to leave a note here to complain about the culture of current stackoverflow.

Before I asked this question, I invested days to dive the socket and surveyed relevant questions. It may seem to be native for some viewers but I really can't understand why some think of it a bad question. One's question can always be too native and simple for others, but it is hard for the owner and he can only grow by learning. It can also give opportunities for others who may encounter the same challenge. Let's keep stackoverflow open.

Comment: This error can occur when the backlog is too high. Try adding an appropriate value to *s.listen()* Not sure what you're hoping your client code will do apart from run forever and flood the communication pipeline. *accept()* will not break existing socket connections

Comment: You are throwing away the accepted socket, which will get reset because you haven’t read the incoming data. Don’t do that. Your test is not realistic.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you so much. Do you mind transferring your comment to an answer so I can accept that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `conn` object returned by `accept()` is reference-counted. When the second connection is assigned to `conn` the first object is no longer referenced and is garbage-collected, which closes the connection. You have to save each connection.